# Retrieve Data data once time Firebase instead of onSnapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data once time instead to using onSnapshot.

```
    import { onSnapshot, collection  } from 'firebase/firestore';

function App() {
  const [books , setbooks] = useState([]);
  console.log(books);
  
     useEffect(() => {
       onSnapshot(collection(db,'books'),(snapshot)=>{
         setbooks(snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
       })
       
      },[]);
```

Comment: Did you see [getting data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent while [getting the data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDocs(collection(db,'books')).then((snapshot)=>{
    setbooks(snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
  })   
},[]);
```

Comment: Thank you Frank,
I tried to use  getDocs then I got empty array

Comment: That seems unexpected, given that it's the exact same query otherwise. Can you edit your question to show the code you used and what you get in a way that we're all looking at the same? For example, if you `console.log` the problem rather than calling `setbooks` can you show the difference between when you use `onSnapshot` vs `getDocs`?